# What are the hidden trophies?

Tags: achievements, ps3, goldeneye-007

I am looking through my list of Trophies for ***Goldeneye 007: Reloaded*** on the PlayStation 3 and there is one hidden trophy I am missing.

If you order the list by "original order" it appears between "Clobbering" and "Hat Trick" - which makes me wonder if it is an online (public match) trophy.

Anybody have any ideas?

Searching online I only found a list of the following 3 hidden trophies, all of which I have already...

1. Dance Commander - Surrender to the music in "Nightclub"
2. Rocket Man - Kill an enemy with the RPG in "Dam"
3. Royal Flush - In "Facility", successfully kill the enemy in the toilet cubicle without any shots being fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PS3Trophies.org](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/goldeneye-007-reloaded/trophies/) has the full list of Goldeneye 007: Reloaded trophies, including the secret ones. Hopefully using that list you can figure out which secret trophies you're missing.

Here's the full list:

- Rocket Man: Kill an enemy with the RPG in 'Dam'.
- Royal Flush: In 'Facility', successfully kill the enemy in the toilet cubicle without any shots being fired.
- Welcome to Russia: Make the initial rendezvous with 006 in 'Dam'.
- Dance Commander: Surrender to the music in 'Nightclub'.
- Cheated: Public Match: Get killed the most times by Oddjob's hat (min 3 deaths).

Comment: Excelent! Seems the one I was missing is.. ***Cheated*** - Public Match: Get killed the most times by Oddjob's hat (min 3 deaths)